# Error creating custom pages from local plugin within GatsbyJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

My goal is creating pages from local plugin. I wrote a custom plugin named `my-custom-plugin`. I've also installed `gatsby-plugin-page-creator` plugin to automatically create pages from my components outside default `pages` directory.

This is my project structure:

```
plugins
    /my-custom-plugin
        /gatsby-node.js
        /package.json
src
    /components
        /pages
            /single.js
gatsby-config.js
gatsby-node.js
...etc
```

gatsby-config.js (from root):

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        `my-custom-plugin`,
        {
            resolve: `gatsby-plugin-page-creator`,
            options: {
                path: `${__dirname}/src/components/pages`,
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

plugins/my-custom-plugin/gatsby-node.js

```
const path = require('path')
const location = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', '/src/components/pages')
exports.createPages = ({ actions }) => {
    const { createPage } = actions
    createPage({
        path: `/sample-page`,
        component: `${location}/single.js`,
        context: {
            slug: 'sample-page'
        }
    })
}
```

Unfortunately, I got error message `The plugin "my-custom-plugin" created a page with a component that doesn't exist` when running gatsby develop. Am I doing wrong? Any help?

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/packages/gatsby-plugin-page-creator

You don't need a custom plugin. The README states that you only need to insert the config into `gatsby-config.js`.

Your current local plugin tries to do exactly that what the page-creator plugin already does.

Comment: Of course I know that. But my purpose is to cleaning up `gatsby-node.js` which lies in root project.

Comment: And still your local plugin is not necessary. You can do it like React's docs site: https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/blob/0c6a26ff9e86fa0631db1a15f5235485241ec6ab/gatsby-node.js